# Parse json with empy string key in powershell

Tags: json, powershell-4.0

ConvertFrom-Json fails with message "Cannot process argument because value of "name" is not valid."
`"{ """": ""test""}" | ConvertFrom-Json`

Is there better way than doing it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**While the [JSON RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) *does* permit empty keys**<sup>[1]</sup>
, **`ConvertFrom-Json` does *not***, unfortunately, for technical reasons: it returns objects of type `[pscustomobject]`, which are not permitted to have a property whose name is the empty string.

By contrast, PowerShell's `[hashtable]` (`[System.Collections.Hashtable]`) type and its ordered-keys sibling (`[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]`) *do* permit entries with empty-string key values (1 per instance).

`ConvertFrom-Json` doesn't offer creating hashtables, but the **third-party [newtonsoft.json](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/newtonsoft.json/1.0.1.2) module** does. The module is a wrapper around the widely used and [Microsoft-recommended](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) [Json.NET library](http://json.net). It comes with alternative cmdlets `ConvertFrom-JsonNewtonsoft` and `ConvertTo-JsonNewtonsoft`:

```
PS> '{ "": "test"}' | ConvertFrom-JsonNewtonsoft

Name                           Value
----                           -----
                               test
```

**Update, as of Oct 2020**: The module was last updated in May 2019, and **the bundled `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` assembly is  quite old:** it is version `8.0`, whereas the [current](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) version as of this writing is `12.0`. The module's source code can be found [here](https://github.com/qbikez/ps-entropy/tree/master/newtonsoft.json/src).

The output type is `[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]`, i.e., a hashtable with ordered keys, and in this case is the equivalent of the following ordered hashtable literal:
`[ordered] @{ '' = 'test' }`

You can use either `.''` or `['']` to reference the entry with the empty key:

```
PS> $o = $'{ "": "test"}' | ConvertFrom-JsonNewtonsoft
PS> $o.'', $o['']
test
test
```

#### Installation

In PowerShell v5 without additional setup, and in v4 (and also v3) after having installed the [PowerShell PackageManagement modules](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51451), you can install the module from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) as follows from an *elevated* console:

```
Install-Module Newtonsoft.Json
```

Alternatively, use `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser Newtonsoft.Json` to install for the current user only.

---

<sup>[1] A JSON name (key) is defined as a `string` (`member = string name-separator value`), and a "string is a sequence of *zero or more* Unicode characters" (emphasis added).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell 7.1.3 at least, `ConvertFrom-Json` has a switch `-AsHashTable` which will allow it to handle empty keys.

```
PS> '{ "": "test" }' | ConvertFrom-Json
ConvertFrom-Json: The provided JSON includes a property whose name is an empty string, this is only supported using the -AsHashTable switch.

PS> '{ "": "test" }' | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable

Name    Value
----    -----
        test
```